# A seemingly intuitive general conclusion from continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Assume a function $f: \mathbb{R}^{n} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{m}$ is continuous at in an open set $S \subseteq D_{f}$, the domain of $f$. That is,
\begin{equation}
\forall x \in S, \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0, \forall y \in S, \lVert y-x\rVert < \delta \longrightarrow \lVert f\left(y\right)-f\left(x\right)\rVert < \epsilon. 
\end{equation}
Suppose that a predicate $P\left(f,x_{0}\right)$ holds for function $f$ at a point $x_{0} \in S$, where $P$ is a general predicate about a quantity. For instance, P can be the proposition "Jacobian of f at $x_{0}$ is nonzero if $f$ is continuously differentiable in $S$" (although in this case, continuity of $f^{\prime}$ should be emphasized). We can intuitively accept the following proposition:
\begin{equation}
\exists \delta > 0, \forall x, \lVert x-x_{0} \rVert < \delta \longrightarrow P(f,x).
\end{equation}
In other words, continuity indicates the validity of a property in a region if it is valid at a point in the region. Is there a systematic way to construct a proof using the rule of contradiction?

Comment: There are many properties $P(f,x_0)$ for which this is false, e.g. $f(x_0)=0$.

Comment: A systematic way to construct a proof of what?